# Running PHP file using crontab

Tags: php, cron

I need to run a PHP file every 1 hour.

What I'm doing is:

sudo crontab -e

(In the editor) * 01 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/devicecheck.php

But somehow, it's not working. The command works on the command line. Before this, I was trying php /var/www/devicecheck.php

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute devicecheck.php  every 1 hour try the following:

**Method A :: Execute the script using php from the crontab**

```
# crontab -e
00 * * * * /usr/bin/php/var/www/devicecheck.php
```

**Method B: Run the php script using URL from the crontab**

If your php script can be invoked using an URL, you can lynx, or curl, or wget to setup your crontab as shown below.

The following script executes the php script (every hour) by calling the URL using the lynx text browser. Lynx text browser by default opens a URL in the interactive mode. However, as shown below, the -dump option in lynx command, dumps the output of the URL to the standard output.

```
00 * * * * lynx -dump http://www.yourwebsite.com/yourscript.php
```

The following script executes the php script (every 5 minutes) by calling the URL using CURL. Curl by default displays the output in the standard output. Using the “curl -o” option, you can also dump the output of your script to a temporary file as shown below.

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/curl -o temp.txt http://www.yourwebsite.com/yourscript.php
```

The following script executes the php script (every 10 minutes) by calling the URL using WGET. The -q option indicates quite mode. The “-O temp.txt” indicates that the output will be send to the temporary file.

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q -O temp.txt http://www.yourwebsite.com/yourscript.php
```

**UPDATE::**

```
# chmod a+x /home/username/yourscript.php
# crontab -e
00 * * * * /home/username/yourscript.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Script should have execute permission. Give it by

`chmod +x  /var/www/devicecheck.php`

Also check `/var/log/syslog` for Errors.

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work with [wget](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/wget/). You maybe have to install wget first. After it will allow you to run php scripts from a cronjob.
The syntax looks like:

```
 * 01 * * */usr/local/bin/wget "http://localhost/devicecheck.php"
```

Where /usr/local/bin/wget points to the directory where wget is installed.
If you wish no output just add '-O /dev/null', like this:

```
 * 01 * * */usr/local/bin/wget "http://localhost/devicecheck.php" -O /dev/null
```

You can also pass parameters in the url:

```
 * 01 * * */usr/local/bin/wget "http://localhost/devicecheck.php?task=somevalue" -O /dev/null
```

Comment: why downvote? provide feedback please, so i can do better!

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted you but, you don't need to use wget. Running it locally works. Just give your php file the execute permission. And, if you want to run it every hour, it should be
00 * * * * command.