# How to save a blob (AJAX response) into a named file (JSON type) into my server NOT in user computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, file-handling

I have read almost all topics around about creating an URL from (or downloading) a blob in a computer, however, I need something different:

(1) to save a blob *in own server* into a JSON file, then

(2) to optimize the way to update a database using the data stored in the JSON.

I tried all variants of code below with no success

```
var blob = new Blob(response, { type: contentType });
var file = new File([blob], filename, {type: contentType, lastModified: Date.now()});
```

where the **response** was the *parsedJSON* from the code below.

Would it be better to already have a file with empty content in the server instead, open it and update it from the blob (then close it)?

My purpose is to download the response content from the AJAX query (from an API) onto my server (not into any client computer in browser) and then update the respective values in a database table.

The use case is as follows: I receive a price list (about 40,000 items) from an API using a cron then I have to update the product prices in the database on my server.

Let's look at the code below:

```
<div id="app">
    <p style="text-align: center; margin-top: 50px;">
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" style="font-size: 15px;"></i><br>
        please wait to load the list of items here...
    </p>
</div>

<script>
var settings = {
  "url": "https://www.notimportant/etc/",
  "method": "GET",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "GUID": "something"
  },
};


$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
  var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(response);
  
                                                  console.log(parsedJSON[0]); /* <= to see the structure of each object in the response array */
console.log('total items: ' + parsedJSON.length);
  
   var template = `
<p>List of items</p>
{{#each this}}
<div>{{plusOne @index}} - Code: {{ProductCode}} - Name: {{ProductName}} - Price: {{ProductPrice}}</div>
{{/each}}
`;

Handlebars.registerHelper('plusOne', function(index) {
    index++;
    return index;
});
  var show = Handlebars.compile(template);
  $('#app').html(show(parsedJSON));
});
        </script>
```

So far so good, I could check using Handlebars JS the results into a browser (and see also in console the object structure received from API). However my purpose is to use each object from the array **parsedJSON** to update values in a table. I could make something as

```
for(i = 0; i < parsedJSON.length; i++) { // use here $.post to send ProductCode, ProductName and ProductPrice to a php file where I execute a query to update each product into the database

var ProductCode = parsedJSON[i].ProductCode;
var ProductName = parsedJSON[i].ProductName;
var ProductPrice = parsedJSON[i].ProductPrice;

  $.post("update_db.php", {code: ProductCode, name: ProductName, price: ProductPrice}, function(data, status){
    console.log("Product " + ProductCode + " update = " + status);
  });
}

alert("all products' update was finished");
```

however, that would create ~ 40,000 single queries into my database (which is not ok at all).

I would prefer instead to save the array *in the server* (to save the response blob, create a file from it, name it **myJSONfile.json**, then in php use `$myfileaddress = $base + "myJSONfile.json"`, read it with `$myfile = file_get_contents($myfileaddress)`, then `$myJson = json_decode($myfile, true)` and then update the database using `foreach($array as $item) {// update each row in products table in database`, etc. }

I doubt however that I could run a multi-query with 40,000 components (or a prepared statement that large, even if I largely increase the allowed memory - I would prefer not to do it). If I am wrong please explain me why.

For the moment, my code is just sending queries one by one, which is not something I would keep doing (I'd better use PHP only or JavaScript only in order to create a single connection to the db, not many as of now).

I actually receive an almost instant response - the alert **all products' update was finished** for full list of products, but then the PHP response messages keep coming in console, too, during some pretty long time about successfully updating each row (talk about few minutes) which isn't something I expected.

I would use something elegant, let's say to use 500 queries in a single transaction (and make the entire update in just 80 steps instead of a full 40,000 simple queries), but not sure how to set everything right.

My point in downloading the full JSON instead of updating each product through a separate API request (plus update) is to query the external server just one time (using a cron) instead of many times, and doing further processing of the data in my own server instead. In the real situation, each product comes from the API with about 20 parameters, not just 3 (Code, Name and Price), but that's not relevant for the issues in question. (Also, sorry for some small inadvertences in the code shown in separate snippets, but I typed quickly instead of any copy-paste from the production files - I'm not writing now from the computer where I work the project in question).

### Final edit

I finally wrote the more compact code below which works just fine (*prepared statement with UPDATE*). Instead of posting it as a separate answer, I will insert it here:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "someuser";
$password = "somepassw";
$dbname = "somedb";

// requiring data from API

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.notimportant/etc/",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"{\"name\": null, \"stores\": null, \"products\": []}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "GUID: something",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

// echo $response;
$data = json_decode($response);
echo "Product count: " . count($data) . "<br>\n";
echo "Preparing to save products to database... <br>\n";

// end receiving data from API

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `my_table` SET `price` = ?, `stock` = ? WHERE `my_table`.`product_id` = ?"); 
$stmt->bind_param("dii", $price, $stock, $id);

// set parameters and execute
foreach($data as $productInfo) {
    $price = $productInfo->RetailPrice;
    $stock = $productInfo->Stock;
    $id = $productInfo->ProductId;
    $stmt->execute();
}

echo "Update was ok";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

?>
```

@Bravemaster suggestions were helpful, the code runs now in less than 10 seconds so it's an acceptable solution for the moment. Point (2) is pretty solved, and (1) seems to be not useful anymore (as it makes no sense to use both *file_put_contents* and *file_get_contents*). I also vote Bravemaster's input as the accepted answer - for his gracious contribution to my code. All 40k+ queries went smoothly in a single batch. What's left is to add some more data validation (to be in the safe side) and to set the cron process (not really an issue).

Comment: I'm looking at one of the .sql files exported from a MySql db under PhpAdmin. The first 50 lines are setting encoding, time-zone and creating two tables. All 122 entries for one of the tables are inserted with a single statement. Pretty sure I've done thousands at once in the past. The yellow highlighted text at the following link seems to be unambiguous. https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-insert-multiple-rows/#:~:text=To%20add%20multiple%20rows%20to,lists%20of%20values%20for%20insertion.

Comment: @enhzflep I am not sure if INSERT works the same as UPDATE in the context you mentioned, because I have also to check with WHERE clause for each query.

Comment: 40000 queries is not that much, unless they're coming from hundreds of simultaneous client requests. You're planning to let cron do the task, most modern servers can handle that amount quite easily.

Comment: I need the cron to do the task few times daily so I finish the business with the API end point then internally update 40000 prices and quantities. That last phase I need to not take too much time. Any code to automate the process as explained already is welcome - as an answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Eve Comments do not give us any reputation. SO is for [minimal reproducible problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I think the problem here is you are asking too many questions at once. Splitting it into smaller problems and posting them in several questions (or finding them in SO) will make people less unhappy.

Comment: @Eve, I think you misunderstood me. Breaking a big problem into smaller, tiny ones is not for SO answerers. It's for sake of you. In the process, you will recap your problem and might get an idea of where you went wrong or what you were missing. Moreover, it'll be much easier for other devs to understand your problem better and hopefully many of them will help you. You accepted my answer, but I doubt my answer was really a fit for your problem. Since your post is too long and asks many questions, I wasn't sure what you were asking. Neither other people.

Comment: And if you're facing an issue with serial downvotes (by fixed number of stalkers), contact SE moderators. But I think there is nothing like serial downvotes for you in SO.

Comment: @bravemaster, I played with the API in Postmaster to test the responses exposed by the end point. They went well, only one response had over 25MB (so I had to download the blob in server then further process it). Postman downloaded the blob as a file but this wasn't an option for me (because the server had to download it daily by the cron not me manually in my computer). It suggested a curl php code too, I used it in a php file, in browser the other server slapped me with CORS error (because of my php file not being on same domain). I scrapped the curl and made a workaround in ajax ->to follow

Comment: @bravemaster ->bingo, it worked. Next step was to update in php to the database - because NOT very SURE HOW TO MAKE IT WORK SAFELY by 'fetch .then .then ' - prepared stmts still being the best ones. Transactions were chosen because of big size of blob saved (and as a way to package the datas in more smaller chunks instead of too many, count the chunks and loop forward to the end). As you can see, there were several aspects, my mistake for not splitting all in more questions, however it was just my 1st day here and overall not a too very positive experience for me. A big thank you on the final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to get data from external API in **client side** and **post them again** to your server.

PHP can send get request and receive response **without jQuery**.

You can write php script to get product price list from external API like the following:

```php
$url = "https://www.notimportant/etc/";
$header = ['GUID' => 'something']

echo "Sending request to API server...\n";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo "Received response\n";
curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($response);
echo "Product count: " . count($data) . "\n";
echo "Saving products to database...";
foreach($data as $productInfo) {
   save_data($productInfo); // you need to implement save_data
}
echo "Products saved. Exiting"\n;
exit(0);
```

If you want to know how to write string (JSON response in this case) to file, refer to this: [How to put the a string into a text file in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440912/how-to-put-the-a-string-into-a-text-file-in-php)

If you want to know how to execute MySQL query **using prepared statements**, refer to this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

If you want to know how to send https request with custom header, refer to this post: [Send GET HTTPS request with custom headers PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022695/send-get-https-request-with-custom-headers-php)

If you want to know how to execute a php script on a regular basis using crontab, refer to this post: [Running PHP file using crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553370/running-php-file-using-crontab)

([Don't worry](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398955/why-someone-not-answering-a-question-can-downvote-it-while-commenting-mostly-use#comment-779682), they're all stackoverflow posts)

> I would use something elegant, let's say to use 500 queries in a single transaction (and make the entire update in just 80 steps instead of a full 40,000 simple queries), but not sure how to set everything right.

Transaction won't improve performance, transaction is never meant for performance but for data integrity. Making 40,000 simple queries and executing them all at once (or one by one, if you say so) is the best option here.